# Laravel Unit testing - can't access models?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, frameworks, phpunit

I'm trying to get unittesting to work in Laravel. This is my test method:

```
public function testCreateUser()
{
    $response = $this->call('GET', 'users');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

My route:

```
Route::get('users', function(){
    return User::first();
});
```

If i start the server and make a call from PostMan this works fine. But if I run the test i get a status code 500, and i have no idea why!

If i replace the route with:

```
Route::get('users', function(){
    return "test";
});
```

.. everything works fine and the test passes.
Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Check your `laravel.log` file for more detailed errors.

Comment: Are your controllers namespaced? Are your unit tests namespaced?

Comment: Thanks @pseudocode ... I checked the log and found that it was a $_SERVER variable, that was causing problems since there was no server started..... :)